# Radius of Convergence of a power series with multi valued coefficient function

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Im trying to find radius of convergence of series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n$, where 
$b_n=\begin{cases}
\lambda^{-n},  & \text{if $n$ is not a multiple of 3} \\
0, & \text{if $n$ is a multiple of 3}
\end{cases}$

Not sure how to do this any advice would be welcome,
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As long as it converges, you may rewrite the series as

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^{-n}x^n - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda^{-3k}x^{3k}$$

and study both series separately. Can you finish?

Comment: Yes I can, thank you!